# div append based on input

Tags: jquery, html, input, append

I need to append the first div to second div on Add button's click and add a minus button while appending. 
Clicking on Minus button will remove the appended div.

While appending second time, then it show be seen as another div box.

Like one box then another box.

Only after user gives input it should be appended.

```html
<div id="question_det">
  <input type="text" value="" id="question" name="question[]">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="1">star</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="2">nps</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="3">comment</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="4">option</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="5">check</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="Add">
</div>
<div id="append"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've changed the `id`s to `class` attribute because if you want to duplicate elements you can't set them `id` attribute because `id` attribute must be unique.

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  var cloned = $('.question_det').clone();
  cloned.appendTo($('#append'));
  var remove = $('<button>remove</button>').insertAfter(cloned.find('.add'));
  remove.click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.question_det').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question_det">
  <input type="text" value="" id="question" name="question[]">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="1">star</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="2">nps</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="3">comment</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="4">option</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="5">check</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" name="add" class="add" value="Add">
</div>
<div id="append"></div>
```

**Update**

If you want to add a conditional statement to the code that append a `div` based on radio button's value you can do something like this:

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  // check wich div you should copy from the radio buttons
  var selected = $('.div_type:checked').val();
  // defined the cloned selector based on the choosen radio button's value
  var selector = selected == 1 ? '.question_det' : '.opt2';
  var cloned = $(selector).first().clone();
  cloned.appendTo($('#append'));
  var remove = $('<button>remove</button>').appendTo(cloned);
  remove.click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.container').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.question_det {
  background:#eee;
  border:1px solid #3d3d3d;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.opt2 {
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label><input class="div_type" type="radio" name="type" value="1" checked="checked" />Type 1</label>
<label><input class="div_type" type="radio" name="type" value="2" />Type 2</label>
<hr />
<div class="question_det container">
  <input type="text" value="" id="question" name="question[]">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="1">star</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="2">nps</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="3">comment</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="4">option</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="question_type" value="5">check</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" name="add" class="add" value="Add">
</div>
<div class="opt2 container">
  Opt 2 Opt 2 Opt 2 Opt 2 Opt 2 
</div>
<div id="append"></div>
```

Comment: @Taleeb He just want the logic, the idea. I don't supply a full program. (Also, the second "Add" button doesn't do anything)

Comment: `how to give conditional statements` - Like what?

Comment: like value of radio button then append one div, if another value then append another div like that